# Learn Ruby The Hard Way Ex39 - Understanding Buckets

Tags: ruby, data-structures, hash, buckets

Can somebody please explain the concept of buckets simply to me. I understand a `Dict` is an array of arrays, I cannot for the life of me make sense of this first block of code though and can't find anything online that explains `num_buckets`. If you could explain it line by line that would be great.

```
module Dict
  def Dict.new(num_buckets=256)
  # Initializes a Dict with the given number of buckets.
  aDict = []
  (0...num_buckets).each do |i|
    aDict.push([])
  end

  return aDict
end
```

Comment: The creation and initialization of `aDict` could have been written, `aDict = Array.new(num_buckets) {[]}`, in which case the `return` would not have been needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is meant to implement a data structure called [Hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). It is the data structure of Ruby's built-in `Hash` class.

Hash tables use the hashing of keys as indexes. Because there are limited number of possible indexes, **collision** (i.e, different keys have the same hashing) happens. [**Separate chaining**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining) is one common method for collision resolution. Keys are inserted into buckets. `num_buckets` here is the number of buckets. Different keys with the same hashing are in the same bucket.

An image illuatrating separate chaining from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#/media/File:Hash_table_5_0_1_1_1_1_1_LL.svg):

[image]

Comment: Yu, not having a computer science background, this is something I didn't know. Interesting. What happens when a bucket becomes full? (Will buckets have buckets?) I'm not sure the OP understands the module is not to be mixed into a class or how the module method is used (e.g., `Dict.new(512)`, I presume).

Comment: @CarySwoveland With this *separate chaining* implementation, a bucket is never really *full* as each bucket is a linked list. However, if the keys are too many, the performance of hash table becomes poor, then **rehashing** happens, for instance, 512 buckets becomes 1024 buckets, and every key will be calculated their new hashing value according to the new bucket number.  Withe the other common *open addressing* implementation, the bucket array might be full, so rehashing must be done before that.